# Why using thread resulting increase in execution time in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, c++11, thread-safety

below is the code I am trying to test with and without thread .

```
void print1()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100000)
    {
        i++;
    }
}

void print2()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100)
    {
        i++;
    }
}

void main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    print1();
    print2();
    //std::thread worker1(print1);
    //std::thread worker2(print2);
    //worker1.join();
    //worker2.join();

    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto duration =std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( end - start);

    std::cout << "Elapsed time " << duration.count() << std::endl;
}
```

First I am calling print1 & print2 functions directly . I am getting time around 0 ms . If I comment `print1() & print2()` and enable thread like below ,

```
//  print1();
//  print2();
    std::thread worker1(print1);
    std::thread worker2(print2);
    worker1.join();
    worker2.join();
```

I am getting `2ms` . But If we run two functions on parallel shouldn't it decrease the output time ? on the contrary it is increasing the time . Am I missing anything ?

The functions print1 & print2 is not doing anything with the result , so the compiler may optimize the code . So , I tried cout in both print1() and print2() function . still I am seeing same behavior.

Does it take time to start and shutdown the thread ? in that case always these two operations will be an overhead for performance ?

Comment: These are not good functions to test. The functions `print1` and `print2` have absolutely zero function and no side-effects. Therefore, they can be completely optimized away. If you're not compiling with optimizations, then your test is useless. If you _are_ compiling with optimizations, your time increase is likely to be the overhead of starting threads. Note that benchmarking an operation as short as 2ms is difficult to begin with. You typically need to use much longer operations and perform statistical analysis. Benchmarking is not easy.

Comment: very short explanation: creating and managing threads has a (large) cost. You'll have a gain with multithreading when each thread has a lot of job to do. There are patterns to limit the effect of the overhead.

Comment: With all this said, you can probably get closer to what you wanted to be testing by doing the following: 1) make your counters global and `volatile`; 2) count to much larger values; 3) introduce randomness so the compiler cannot optimize the counting away (_e.g._ `count += rand() % 2;`) - beware that's probably not actually thread-safe, illustrative only; 4) output the values of your counters at the end of the program to ensure there is a side-effect; 5) in your non-threaded case, spawn and join threads that execute empty functions, to make thread management overhead similar in both tests

Comment: Just by looking at code I see you are a beginner. I really recommend you to avoid using threads until you master basics. Mutithreading looks easy but if you have bugs in code outcome is nondeterministic. So beginner may thing his code works why in fact it has serous problems. You will use your time more effectively if you postpone use of threads. Note that you `print1` and `print2` do not have any visible effects, so optimize will drop the whole thing.

Comment: Make some functions that do not do any real work and then complain about the do-nothing functions taking too much time doing nothing. Great! This is just great!

Comment: On my machine, spinning up a thread means allocating (by default) a 512 KiB stack of *wired memory*, initializing a thread id structure, scheduling that thread to run in its preëmptive time slice.  All of that overhead takes time.